# Ideas for listing files, directories, sub files & sub directories without recursion in ftp server

Tags: java, ftp, java-threads

I'm trying to produce file listing of a given directory and it's sub directories in a ftp server.

The server works fine, and I have been successfully able to produce the file listing of the current directory. When I try to list the subdirectories and their files is where it gets complicated.

I was asked not to use a recursion algorithm, so I did some research of my own. I have tried using threads (for every directory found, start a new thread), but I wasn't able to keep my connection stable and open. Any ideas on how to do so correctly with threads, or other alternatives?

EDIT: below is my code, when using the recursive statement (last line of code), it works

```
   class TEST {
        public static synchronized void main(String[] args) {
        String server = args[0]; //server,path will be given as an arguments
        String pass = "SOMEPASS";
        String user = "SOMEUSER";
        int port = 21;
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                System.out.println("Connect failed");
                return;
            }
            boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
                return;
            }
           /*START THE FILE LISTING HERE*/

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // logs out and disconnects from server
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void scanDir(FTPClient client, String path) throws IOException {
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles(path); // Search all the files in the current directory
        
        for (int j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(files[j].getName()); // Print the name of each files
        }
        FTPFile[] directories = client.listDirectories(path); // Search all the directories in the current directory
        for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
            String dirPath = directories[i].getName();
            System.out.println(dirPath); // Print the path of a sub-directory
            scanDir(client,dirPath); // Call recursively the method to display the files in the sub-directory DONT WANT TO DO THAT...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion can always replaced with lists an vice versa. Have two lists: one where the found items go, and one where the todo-directories go. so whenever you encounter a subdirectory, add that subdir to the todo-list. Once you're done iterating through the current directory, grab the next one from the todo-list. If the todo-list is empty, program is done.

Comment: I personally would love to use recursion, it's a task asked me to do by my bosses/teachers, and the purpose is that they would like to see if I can handle a project where recursion will be problematic.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl one of the problems of recursion is that it's not efficient memory management, as you need to stack:push the current state, create a new one, initialize, continue algorithm. same when coming down. an additional 'problem' is memory consumption, because that is harder to calculate and control too.
Mind, that those are extreme and rare cases. Most filesystems for example limit the depth of diretories oder the addressable path length, so this is usually not a problem. Where recursion memory and speed get a problem is simulation models, for example.

Comment: @JayC667 any chance you could provide me with a simple example? or direct me to a link where i can look at sample code?

Comment: Post your code first, then you'll get an example.

Comment: @JayC667 wouldn't it be better to use a 'stack<FTPFile>' for the subdirs?

Comment: Yes. In single-threaded or not-thread-safe methods, stacks and (array)lists have the exact same functionality in the background. in multithreaded context, stacks could be optimized further. but here it does not really matter. java.util.Stack<> derives from Vector<>, which is made thread-safe (synchronized methods), so it is slower than ArrayList in single-threaded context. as your task is far away from any multi-threading, we can ignore that and use the faster approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here is an *example* of how to handle it non-recursively, but with lists.

Mind, that this example is based on /accessing the local filesystem, but can easily be rewritten/extended for any kind of hierarchial/recursive structure.

```
package stackoverflow.nonrecursivefilesearch;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class NonRecursiveFileSearch {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final File searchDir = new File("D:\\test\\maven-test"); // set one

        System.out.println("\nOld Java");
        printDirs(listFiles_old(searchDir, true, true), "OLD: Depth first, include dirs");
        printDirs(listFiles_old(searchDir, true, false), "OLD: Breadth first, include dirs");
        printDirs(listFiles_old(searchDir, false, true), "OLD: Depth first, exclude dirs");
        printDirs(listFiles_old(searchDir, false, false), "OLD: Breadth first, exclude dirs");

        System.out.println("\nNew java.io with streams");
        printDirs(listFiles_newIO(searchDir, true), "Java NIO, include dirs");
        printDirs(listFiles_newIO(searchDir, false), "Java NIO, exclude dirs");
    }

    /**
     * this is the way to 'manually' find files in hierarchial/recursive structures
     *
     * reminder: "Depth First" is not a real depth-first implementation
     * real depth-first would iterate subdirs immediately.
     * this implementation iterates breadth first, but descends into supdirs before it handles same-level directories
     * advantage of this implementation is its speed, no need for additional lists etc.
     *
     * in case you want to exclude recursion traps made possible by symbolic or hard links, you could introduce a hashset/treeset with
     * visited files (use filename strings retrieved with canonicalpath).
     * in the loop, check if the current canonical filename string is contained in the hash/treeset
     */
    static public ArrayList<File> listFiles_old(final File pDir, final boolean pIncludeDirectories, final boolean pDepthFirst) {
        final ArrayList<File> found = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<File> todo = new ArrayList<>();

        todo.add(pDir);

        while (todo.size() > 0) {
            final int removeIndex = pDepthFirst ? todo.size() - 1 : 0;
            final File currentDir = todo.remove(removeIndex);
            if (currentDir == null || !currentDir.isDirectory()) continue;

            final File[] files = currentDir.listFiles();
            for (final File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    if (pIncludeDirectories) found.add(file);
                    // additional directory filters go here
                    todo.add(file);
                } else {
                    // additional file filters go here
                    found.add(file);
                }
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    static private void printDirs(final ArrayList<File> pFiles, final String pTitle) {
        System.out.println("====================== " + pTitle + " ======================");
        for (int i = 0; i < pFiles.size(); i++) {
            final File file = pFiles.get(i);
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        System.out.println("============================================================");
    }

    /**
     * this is the java.nio approach. this is NOT be a good solution for cases where you have to retrieve/handle files in your own code.
     * this is only useful, if the any NIO class provides support. in this case, NIO class java.nio.file.Files helps handling local files.
     * if NIO or your target system does not offer such helper methods, this way is harder to implement, as you have to set up the helper method yourself.
     */
    static public Stream<Path> listFiles_newIO(final File pDir, final boolean pIncludeDirectories) throws IOException {
        final Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(pDir.toPath(), 100,
                (path, basicFileAttributes) -> {
                    final File file = path.toFile(); // conversion to File for easier access (f.e. isDirectory()), could also use NIO methods
                    return (pIncludeDirectories || !file.isDirectory() /* additional filters go here */ );
                });
        return stream;

    }
    static private void printDirs(final Stream<Path> pStream, final String pTitle) {
        System.out.println("====================== " + pTitle + " ======================");
        pStream.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("============================================================");
    }
}
```

AND, one must add, `java.nio.file.Files.find()` might be implemented recursively. But as it's just one call, this maybe could count as 'non-recursive' too.

ALSO, as the OP stated in comments, one might use Stack or other FIFO/LIFO collections. LIFO for a mixed depth-first, FIFO for breadth-first approach.

Comment: If this suffices your requirements, you can mark this as the accepted answer. More points for me, and others see that it is solved. Also a note to your coding style vs mine: whenever you have helper functions, like my two functions, throw back as many real exceptions as possible/useful; only catch exceptions and handle them locally, when it is a direct requirement to your algorithm. There's also the possibility of catch/wrap/throw for more specific exception handling.